# Which is the correct way to initialize a union/struct?

Tags: c, xc8

I have got the following union:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t LSB;
        uint8_t MSB;
    };
    int16_t     complete;
}uint16ByteT;
```

Know I want to use my type and initialize the variable. After scanning SO  ( I thought) I found the solution:

```
uint16ByteT   myVariable  = {0};
```

But my compiler gives me an Error message:

> simple type required for "@"

Normally the xc8 compiler uses the "@" to bring a variable at a specific address.

Comment: `uint16ByteT` vs `uint16Byte`. If this is just a typo here, the error doesn't seem related to the code shown.

Comment: Which compiler are you use ?

Comment: *for "@"*? Can you please copy and paste the error message verbatim? It will help making this a [mcve].

Comment: It's exactly the error message a wrote above, Sorry about the typo

Comment: I sense some fuzziness in the meaning of "exactly the same", please copy&paste the literal error output of your compiler. Also show how you invoke the compiler, @KeineLust might have a point in his answer -- what you do here requires C11.

Comment: my compiler: xc8

Comment: It seems that xc8 doesn't support C11: _This compiler conforms to the ISO/IEC 9899:1990 Standard for programming languages. This is commonly called the C90 Standard. It is referred to as the ANSI C 
Standard in this manual._ In this case you can not use anonym `struct`s (use a name for the inner anonym `struct`)

Comment: I have looked in the manual:  XC8 supports anonym structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize an anonym `struct`/`union` you can use:

```
uint16ByteT myVariable = {{0}, .complete = 0};
```

or simply

```
uint16ByteT myVariable = {{0}};
```

Notice `uint16ByteT` instead of `uint16Byte`

Also notice that you need to compile in C11 mode since anonym `struct`s/`union`s was introduced in this version.

Comment: The initializer from the question should be just as good for initializing to 0.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, maybe is enough, but in this way you skip the warning: `warning: (near initialization for ‘myVariable.<anonymous>’) [-Wmissing-braces]`

Comment: Yes, some compilers will show this. But still not related to the (quite obscure) problem in the question. OP should clarify.

Comment: @KeineLust: You can silence a compiler complaining about missing braces by just giving it what it asks for like: `...  = {{0}};` in this case